# Why are my blender hotkeys changing?

Tags: shortcut, customization, scene

Whenever I try to click an object in the scenes panel, my hotkeys go haywire:

- Left mouse button stops working (I can't deselect, select, drag, etc)
- None of the grab, scale, delete, etc hotkeys work
- Ctrl z goes from undo to change to X-ray mode
- Middle mouse changes view instead of orbiting
- Middle mouse wheel scrolls through animation instead of zooming in/ out

If I open and close my preferences (without changing anything), the hotkeys return to normal. But once I click the scenes panel it reverts to the original problem.

I've tried loading factory settings and opening a different file.

Any idea on what's going on? Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: maybe download newest version?

Comment: Could be that you have an add-on enabled that causes issues. You may want to check if starting Blender with temporary factory default settings through `blender_factory_startup.cmd` avoids the problem.